# jQuery animate element clockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have this code, which I got from one of the stack overflow answers, and I use it to animate element in click event:

```
$(this).animate({ borderSpacing: -180 }, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
    },
duration: 'fast'
}, 'linear')
```

It works perfectly fine, but rotates element anti-clockwise. Is there anyway I could rotate element in opposite direction. When I change border spacing value to positive it rotates only for the first time and never again after. Was looking everywhere for an answer.

Comment: Actually Rory's code was correct, `+ -now + 'deg)'` should do the trick, since currently `now` is negative.

Comment: @Teemu, you are absolutely right. Can you wright it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I'd rather wait for @RoryMcCrossan to re-open their answer.